# What are the allowed ways of creating hyperlinks in docx files?

Tags: docx

I'm currently working on a library that will take docx files as input and use that to build html-pages, due to vague and lack of documentation of docx I have to rely heavily on example output to decide on how to handle certain things. One of these things is hyperlinks.

As far as I have seen so far docx has, at least, two ways of doing hyperlinks:

- Anchor - `<w:hyperlink w:anchor="_Toc000000000" history="1"></w:hyperlink>`

  This seems to be the mostly prefered way of doing things like toc-links.
- Id - `<w:hyperlink w:id="rId7" history="1"></w:hyperlink>`

  This seems to be the only way to specify a url for the hyperlink (with the id being defined in the `.xml.rels` file)

So far so good, my problem is that I have encountered files where they simple specify a rStyle (on the textrun object) value of "Hyperlink" and then seems to believe that this will make the text act as a hyperlink to the title specified in the textrun.

For example a document can contain the following:

```
<w:p>
  <w:pPr>
    <w:pStyle w:val="Heading1"/>
  </w:pPr>
  <w:r>
    <w:t>Introduction</w:t>
  </w:r>
</w:p>
```

And then further down the follwing:

```
<w:p>
  <w:r>
    <w:t>This is a hyperlink to </w:t>
  </w:r>
  <w:r>
    <w:rPr>
      <w:rStyle w:val="Hyperlink"/>
    </w:rPr>
    <w:t>Introduction</w:t>
  </w:r>
  <w:r>
    <w:t>.</w:t>
  </w:r>
</w:p>
```

So my question is, is these kind of "hyperlinks" (`w:p` instead of `w:hyperlink`) actually valid or just something that word or the authors of the files i have is doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say that the docx format is vague and lacks documentation, have you looked at the specs? http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-376.htm (Though I do find them vague at key points.)

There are at least two ways I know of to create links. w:hyperlink is one of them.

The `w:hyperlink` element either links internally or externally, and works more or less how you have discovered.

In the case of an external hyperlink, it will have a relationship id, and an entry in the relationships for this document marked as external that has a uri. The spec says that if the hyperlink is external, the anchor attribute should be ignored, but in practice, I found that Word will stick the anchor part of an external url here. E.g. `http://example.com/page#myAnchor` will store the uri without `#myAnchor` in the relationships and the `anchor` attribute of `hyperlink` will have "myAnchor" without the '#'. You will probably want to check for both.

For internal hyperlinks, the anchor should either match the `name` attribute of a  `w:bookmarkStart` element, or be a special value like "_GoBack" or "_top".

The second case is images that are linked, which is, unfortunately, far more complicated. There will be a `w:drawing` for the image which will have a `docPr` element with a `hlinkClick` element, which will have a relationship id with the destination. The spec seems a bit unclear at this point, but looking at what Word does, it looks like if the relationship is internal, it will be a bookmark name (with '#' prepended), and if external, a uri.

Comment: Hmm, I apologize for bad wording. I should have specified "good documentation". Also I did not include specifications in my use of the word documentation so fully understandable misscommunication. :)

Thanks a lot for the answer!

Comment: No problem. I merely wanted to make sure you were aware of it, even though it wouldn't have answered your question. I find it very helpful for most things, at least as a starting point, and frustrating to no end when key things are just missing or not clearly specified, or when Word seems to behave differently from the spec. :)